# Why can't I cast an instance of a String to Iterable[Char] in Scala

Tags: scala

This line will fail:

```
"Hello".asInstanceOf[Iterable[Char]]
```

But I can pass an instance of a String to a method like this:

```
def someMethod(input: Iterable[Char]): Unit = { ... }
someMethod("Hello")
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String` does not extend `Iterable[Char]`. That explains why casting fails.

However, the Scala Predef [defines an implicit conversion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#wrapString(s:String):scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) from `String` to `WrappedString`, and `WrappedString` *does* extend `Iterable[Char]`. That's why your second example works. The compiler adds the conversion, so the compiled code looks more like this:

```
someMethod(wrapString("Hello"))
```

If you're wondering why it was done this way, it's because `String` is actually `java.lang.String` from the Java standard library (for Java compatibility reasons), so `WrappedString` was created as an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to make `String` fit within the Scala collections library, and an implicit conversion was added to make this nearly seamless.

Comment: Type ascription also succeeds as a way of triggering the implicit conversion: `"Hello": Iterable[Char]`